# Is there a way to take a picture from IP camera using RPI via python code

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, raspberry-pi-zero

I am working on RPI v4 and I am using my mobile camera as an IP camera, using IP WEBCAM app, to take pictures to the raspberry pi
is there a way to make a code such that when I push a button from the GPIO the RPI captures the photo and save it on the file?

I know how to control the GPIO pins but I couldn't find out how to control the camera.

Comment: Yes, this is probably possible. Please, as a new user, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I suppose this would help https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Make-Raspberry-Pi-Webcam-Server-and-Stream-/